# Prove bipartite graph with maximum degree d is a subgraph of a d regular bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, bipartite-graphs

How can I show that every bipartite graph of maximum degree d is a subgraph of some d-regular bipartite graph.

> If something I'm saying could be better mathematically phrased, please let me know. Let's call H our original bipartite graph. Suppose X and Y are the disjoint sets in H. If X has less vertices than Y, we add until equal. Same thing vice versa. Let's say this brings us to a total of d+x vertices on each side. My thought process is, if we can prove that we can create a d regular bipartite graph using the 2(d+x) vertices, H is a subgraph of this new graph. Is this a reasonable approach, if so, how can I go about completing it?

Comment: This approach will work if by "graph" you mean "multigraph"; but if you would like a simple graph, you might need to add a few more vertices on each side, beyond what it takes to make the two sides equal. There are a number of approaches that vary in efficiency (how much bigger the result is than the original graph) and in simplicity.

Comment: @MishaLavrov thanks for the response, I suppose I don't care about how much larger the new graph is so long as it results in a proof. What do you recommend?